# Cannot run code on device

Tags: iphone, code-signing

I have some source code which I had developed and later gave to another team. They signed it with their certificate and provisioning profile.

Now I have the code back and have set the appropriate values in the project properties for code signing identity (with my cert and profile). But when I run the application on a device, I get an error showing the other team's certificate and prompting that the provisioning profile does not exist.

I don't know where it is being referenced.

Can someone please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the Target properties, not just the Project, because it could be overridden there.

Answer (score 2):

Similar thing just happened to me, in my case the "Target" settings were still set to the previous developer's certificate, while my "Project" settings were set to my new certificate. Xcode reported:

"Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: ' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the login keychain"

Boot's answer worked for me - there are "Target" settings for signing that override the "Project" settings, which is why you may have needed to recreate the whole project, if you only changed the "Project" settings.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Active SDK from iphone device to Iphone simulator. This will let you test your code on your iphone simulator. You need a cert if you plan on running your app on your device. (Maybe the code that you got was signed for device).

Answer (score 0):

Under `Project > Edit Project Settings...` click on the `Configurations` menu and select `All Configurations`. Then scroll down to `Code Signing` (or type it into the search field) to verify your provisioning information, changing the `Code Signing Identity` as needed.

Comment: That is what I did. Made sure all configurations have my provisioning profile. But the app won't even compile without showing the code sign error. Had to finally create a new project to be able to run the app.

Comment: That's a puzzler. I always get caught with custom settings in the "Debug", "Release" and "Distribution" configurations. Picking "All Configurations" is a definite help to make sure all the configurations are using the same settings.

Answer (score 0):

connect your iphone, open organizer, there you first need to delete the profile of your other team, and then force an add of your profile (by drag and drop or clicking the + button)

once done, change your code signing settings from the project info window and you should be okay. i faced the same problem and had to do the above to resolve it

Comment: Thanks Raj but the other team works on a different machine. So their profile is not installed on my mac (coz i've never installed it). My profile is already added in the Organizer and the phone. Code signing settings have already been changed. But still getting this error

Comment: oh okay sorry, my mistake, i thought you were using the same iphone device for both machines!

Answer (score 0):

Solution people

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1618.html